# getElementById is working but getElementsByClassName is not working

Tags: javascript, html

It is working with the querySelector, but I have 3 number input fields. It only works on the first one. Second and the third one is not working.

```
const elX = document.querySelector('.sayim');
    const elY = document.querySelector('.tm-qty');

function limit() {
    elY.value=Math.min(Math.round(elX.value),elY.value);
}

elX.onchange=limit;
elY.onchange=limit;
```

The first HTML

```
<input class="sayim" type="number" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="999" name="wc_bookings_field_persons_2855" id="wc_bookings_field_persons_2855">
```

And the second HTML

```
<input class="tm-qty" type="number" step="any" min="0" name="tmcp_checkbox_0_1_quantity" value="0" title="Qty" size="4">
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName is not working` What have you tried that isn't working? What's the HTML?

Comment: You haven't shown us your non-working code, but I would guess that the issue is because `getElementById` returns a single element, where as `getElementsByClassName` will return a collection you need to loop through or access by index.

Answer (score 1):

A class is not clearly. To get the first one whit the classname use [0]

```
const elX = document.querySelector('.sayim')[0];
const elY = document.querySelector('.tm-qty')[0];

function limit() {
    elY.value=Math.min(Math.round(elX.value),elY.value);
}

elX.onchange=limit;
elY.onchange=limit;
```

Comment: I have 3 input fields, it works on the first input field. Second one and the third one is not working. (If I add [0], consol error :Cannot set property 'onchange' of undefined.) Thanks for the answer.